# I am puzzled with the differences between "sh xxx.sh" and "./xxx.sh" for running a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Here, I have a shell script named `load.sh`.

It start my program named "demo" with supervise,
When I run it with `sh load.sh start | stop`, it works well.

However, when I run it with `./load.sh start | stop`, it works bad. the demo is frequently started(and exit) by the supervise.

What's the problem of the two ways of running the shell script?
and is there any problem(bug) in the script cause the supervise frequently restart the demo?
Thanks a lot!

```
#!/bin/bash

cd `dirname $0` || exit
mkdir -p status/demo

dir_name=`pwd`
STR_LIB=${dir_name}/lib

if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${STR_LIB}"
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${STR_LIB}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
fi

start() {
            sleep 1
            bin/supervise.demo -u status/demo bin/demo >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}

stop() {
            if [ -f status/demo/lock ]; then
                supervise_demo_pid=`/sbin/fuser status/demo/lock`
                `ps -ef | grep "$supervise_demo_pid" | grep "supervise.demo" | grep -v grep > /dev/null 2>&1`
                if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "$supervise_demo_pid" != "" ] ; then
                    echo "kill supervise.demo process:"${supervise_demo_pid}
                    kill -9 $supervise_demo_pid
                fi
            fi

            if [ -f status/demo/status ]; then
                demo_pid=`od -An -j16 -N2 -tu2 status/demo/status`
                `ps -ef | grep "$demo_pid" | grep "demo" | grep -v grep > /dev/null 2>&1`
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "kill demo process:"${demo_pid}
                    kill -9 $demo_pid
                fi
            fi
}

case "$1" in
        start)
            stop
            start
            echo "Done!"
            ;;
        stop)
            stop
            echo "Done!"
            ;;
           *)
           echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
           ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sh script.sh` runs the script in `sh`, while running it as `./script.sh` uses whatever is specified on its first "shebang" line - `/bin/bash` in this case.

`sh` and `/bin/bash` might be different shells, so they interpret the script differently. What `sh` is depends on your distribution, $PATH, aliases etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script via `./load.sh start | stop` it runs with processor that is specified in [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). In your case it is bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

What about `sh load.sh start | stop`. In Ubuntu (by default) `sh` is actually just a link and in points to [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).
To check it:

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 16 00:54 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: Moreover, `sh` could be something else than `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

sh foo will search $path for an executable foo
sh ./foo demands execution from the $cwd

both
foo and ./foo run via the shebang as noted herein

all forms will  invoke foo with the perms of the specific file referenced, including suid,guid